# Access Denied for Process.Start() when <identity impersonate="true" />

Tags: c#, asp.net, process, access-denied, impersonation

My head is flat from banging my head with this issue.

I have set `<identity impersonate="true" />` for AD things but when I re-run the app, I get "Accesss Denied" error when Process.Start() is trying to run a command.

So I put: 
   `<identity impersonate="true" userName="domain\user" password="pass" />` then it is now giving me

> The current identity (domain\user) does not have write access to 'c:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files'.

When I put username and password in process.StartInfo, I still get the Access Denied error.

What am I doing wrong?

ps. This is a web service

Comment: It isn't clear just from the question what the command is trying to do; it *could* just be a case of supplying a working path, or using parameters such that it doesn't attempt to use local disk. It *could* be that what you are trying to do is really risky and not recommended ;p What is the command trying to do?

Comment: THe process is trying to run cmd.exe with arg dsmod.

Comment: Propably your impersonated user doesn't have rights to access to cmd.exe or dir `\windows`. But is not a good idea to give that rights either. Try to find a solution that doesn't include `Process.Start`